# Sending Trimble GeoXH GPS data to an Android Tablet using Bluetooth

Tags: gps, android, trimble

Has anyone ever successfully connected a Trimble GeoXH to an android device and consumed the GPS data? I have tried both [Bluetooth GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=googoo.android.btgps&hl=en) and [Bluetooth GPS Mouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Argotronic&hl=en)) apps with no such luck. They both connect to the Trimble but do not consume GPS data. I have enabled mock locations on the Samsung.

I am using Trimble Terrasync software on the handheld to see GPS status. There were a few other posts on here but none using a GeoXH.

Specs:
Tablet = Samsung Galaxy Pro
GPS Device = Trimble GeoXH Geoexplorer 6000 series handheld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple reason that you are not receiving GPS data from the Geo6000 - the Geo doesn't output GPS data on Bluetooth by default.

The Geo 6000 provides Trimble-proprietary GPS data on Com 3 and NMEA data on Com 2 (assuming you have the NMEA option - at some stage Trimble made that an extra-cost option. . . )  What you need is a Windows Mobile / WEHH application which connects / routes Com 2 to a Bluetooth port (probably Com 9) so it can be consumed by other devices via Bluetooth, and for Geo6000 or Geo 7x you can download the "GNSS Connector" application from the Trimble website [here](http://trl.trimble.com/dscgi/ds.py/Get/File-528926/GNSS%20Connector.CAB).

**Disclaimer**: I have not used this utility since Geo 2008 days, but there's not many selections to make in GNSS Connector.  TerraSync Setup / GNSS / NMEA allows you to set up what NMEA sentences you want, a typical set would be GGA, RMC, GSA, GSV, ZDA.